# Serve static files through Nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, caching, nginx

I'm struggling to let Nginx serve static files and tried out about every configuration option I could find. Here's the app's basic structure.

```
ROOT
|_ static
  |_css/
  |_js/
|_ app.py
```

I've read Nginx docs about it, but the files do not seem to cache.
Here's my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
events {
  worker_connections 64;
}
http {

  gzip on; # Enables compression
  gzip_types
    "application/javascript;charset=utf-8" application/javascript text/javascript
    "text/css;charset=utf-8" text/css
    "text/plain;charset=utf-8" text/plain;

  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.tk domain.tk;

    location /static/ {
      alias /home/myuser/myapp/static/;
      add_header  Cache-Control public;
      expires     14d;
      access_log  off;
    }

    location / {
      include     uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/myuser/myapp/myapp.sock; # REPLACE user
    }
   }
  }
```

I'm using a uWSGI server and a Flask application if that matters. The developer console says the app should leverage Browser caching, how do I configure Nginx to work with serving the static files?

Comment: This might be useful to you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-centos-7

Comment: Put `public` in quotation marks so it reads `"public"` and the you could add an additional header `add_header Pragma public;` Don't forget to restart nginx.